# send files via ROS between hosts

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know how to send msgs between two computers. And I try to send txt files through wlan. How can I achieve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112606/send-files-via-ros-between-hosts/) by [isnow4ever](https://answers.ros.org/users/6142/isnow4ever/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One way you may achieve this is by running a rosbridge server and client on both hosts.

http://www.rosbridge.org/doku.php

---

Originally posted by [trianta2](https://answers.ros.org/users/8336/trianta2/) with karma: 293 on 2013-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0